# How to glob match minion in salt master for number containing more than one digit?

Tags: glob, salt-stack, targeting

I just found out that I could not target minion using glob matching if the number to be matched is composed of more than one digit :

```
salt 'mail[1-4]*' test.ping
```

OK

```
salt 'mail[11-14]*' test.ping
```

Does NOT

I know I could use regxp switch for that, but I am just wondering if this is standard behaviour in salt ? (and in python by extension)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior of [shell-style globbing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) that's used in Salt. [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/globbing.html#globbing).

You still can target minions with glob matching, you just have to glob each digit separately.

```
salt 'mail[1-9][1-9]*' test.ping
```

For details on glob see [man 7 glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found these 2 pages before asking anyway, but I am still not able to found the piece of text that explains that specific behaviour. Especially given the fact that this function is called "Unix filename pattern matching". I was expecting something more accurate than these 2 pages. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I edited my answer and added link to the linux man page which describe how the glob-ing works in more detail.